# ModelState still requiring previously required fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate, lightspeed

Subject pretty much says it all - currently working on an application using MVC4 and if I remove a Required attribute from a property in my view model, upon submitting to the controller with this property empty, ModelState.IsValid still returns false citing said property is required.

I have been working around this by calling ModelState.Remove where needed, but this is obviously far from ideal.

I feel this is a pretty straight forward explanation of some rather odd behavior, if I need to provide screenshots and specific code examples I can do so.

Edit:

This is not specific to a certain data type and the solution has been cleaned and rebuilt. I am using LightSpeed ORM but I assume this is completely irrelevant at this level.

Comment: Does it happen for any particular type of value or does it happen to everything like even strings?

Comment: Are you sure that you have recompiled the code, the app pool has been recycled and that the application is using the new assembly where the attribute has been removed from the property?

Comment: try cleaning the solution and rebuilding

Comment: No dice on the clean and rebuild which one of my initial thoughts as well.

Comment: @RyanSchlueter not a specific type either - is happening for strings and ints.

Comment: Have you tried to clear modelstate  ?

Comment: @Kosmo yes. I have update my question with more details.